# How can create one bibliography file for different tex files in one project

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, biber

I am beginner in Tex writing, and writing a report in Texmaker on Ubuntu 13.10. I have separate files for different chapters. Now I want to create one .bib file for all chapters including main file, where I keep references of all files. How can I create .bib file and how can I refer to this file from different files?

Comment: A good guide to start is [Tame the BeaST](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), quick googling also reveals [A BibTeX Guide via Examples](http://www-hep.colorado.edu/~jcumalat/4610_fall_10/bibtex_guide.pdf), [BibTeXing](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxdoc.pdf), [Everything you always wanted to know about BibTeX](http://www.ntg.nl/bijeen/pdf-s.20031113/BibTeX-tutorial.pdf), [Wikipedia: BibTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX), [Managing Citations and Your Bibliography
with BibTex](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/fenn/fenn.pdf).

Comment: You might also want to read [Wikibooks: LaTeX: Bibliography Management](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) and [Wikibooks: LaTeX: More Bibliographies](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies). [Getting to Grips with LaTeX: Bibliographies with BibTeX](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies). [LaTeX tips: Bibliographies](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/bibliographies.html), [How do I create bibliographies in LaTeX?](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/x/J547), http://www.grad.iit.edu/latex/LaTeX/BiblioHelp2.pdf.

Comment: @moewe I think, “Tame the BeaST” is quite hard stuff for a beginner since it goes very deep into macro definitions right from the beginning. I would *not* suggest this one as a starting point.

Comment: @Lupino Probably you're right, but this file really does contain the a lot of the information one needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, you use bibtex. In this [Intro to BibTeX.pdf](http://www.n.ethz.ch/~rephilip/download/Studium%20usw/LaTeX/IntroToBibTeX.pdf) you will find a very basic introduction on how to use bibtex and how to cite referencs throughout your LaTeX document.

There some tools that allow you to more or less automatically generate the bibtex-source for a given reference. One is [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to export whole .bib-files.

GoogleBooks provides bibtex reference source for many of its previewed books: If you found a book you want to cite, click on “about this book” and scroll all the way down to see the option “export as BibTeX”.

Comment: thanks for your response, can I refer from different files to only one .bib file eaisly?

Comment: Yes, of course. As long as both your chapter files and the .bib file are somehow called from out of your TeX master file (the one which has `\documentclass` in it…) and therefore use the same set of .aux-files, this should work perfectly.

Comment: Is .aux-file are updated after compiling or I can update it manually?

Comment: It is updated with every latex run. To see the results you go `latex master` (read the citations you use) -> `bibtex master` (process the bib-file and create a bbl-file out of it) -> `latex master` (pass the information from bbl to aux) -> `latex master` (interpret the aux to solve the cite-macros). I'm not quite shure whether texmaker does this four steps automatically, please refer to texmaker's user manual.